# What does "reintegrate into the labour market" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> A: XYZ helps unemployed individuals *prepare for, find, and maintain suitable employment*.
>
> B: XYZ offers programs and services that help unemployed workers *reintegrate into the labour market and maintain suitable employment*.

**Question:** Is **"reintegrate into the labour market"** equivalent to **"prepare for [employment], find [employment]"**? Do they convey the same idea?

If not, then "maintain suitable employment" in B does not make sense as "maintain" needs to come after one "finds" a job.

Definitions from google and collins-

Reintegrate: restore to a position as a part fitting easily into a larger whole

Labour Market: the market in which employers look and compete for workers and in which workers look and compete for employment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To reintegrate* is basically *to integrate again*.

When someone integrates into a social group, they become part of that group, they are accepted to it.

> He didn't integrate successfully into the Italian way of life.
>
> It's very difficult to integrate yourself into a society whose culture is so different from your own.
>
> Children are often very good at integrating into a new culture.

The labor market is the supply of people who are able and willing to work. When you reintegrate someone into the labor market, you help them enter it again.

Comment: I understand the general idea of it. But, what I don't get is, does "reintegrate into the labour market" mean "prepare for and find jobs"? Are they equivalent?

Comment: @AIQ XYZ prepares you for the labour market, helps you enter it, makes you more noticeable/valuable there.

Comment: @AIQ It doesn’t necessarily mean that they give you a job. With their help, you will become competent enough to get some job offers.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Would you say this is correct or repetitive then: XYZ offers programs and services that help unemployed workers reintegrate into the labour market and find and maintain suitable employment ?

Comment: @AIQ it's correct. Once you are integrated into the labour market, you are able to "find and maintain suitable employment".

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a person Alex. Alex was employed in an multination corporation. But due to some reasons like an accident he could not continue his job and had to resign. Therefore he became unemployed and could not compete with others thus he became detached from Labour market. But this "XYZ policy" would help him seek and get employment using some other skills thus he is again able to compete with others and becomes employed and also he is now part of the Labour market (reintegrated) and he can continue with this job if he wishes.